# Audit logs retrieval in slack

Tags: slack-api, slack

I need to check audit logs for activities done between a timeperiod on my slack account. I couldn't find any API/methods which can help me with audit logs retrieval. I need to see what all users have been added, removed or invited between a given timeframe. Any help on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

There are of course methods to download login ([team.accessLogs](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs)) and integration activity ([team.integrationLogs](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.integrationLogs)), but they only provide a part of the functionality you asked for and the first is only available on paid tier.

However you could develop a small custom app for logging all required activity using the new [Event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). With the Event API your app can subscribe to any [event type](https://api.slack.com/events) you like to log. Whenever an event of that type occures Slack will send a request to your app,  with detailed context information. Your app can then store this info in a file for later retrieval and analysis.

e.g. users added: https://api.slack.com/events/team_join